# jQuery - Horizontal Slider with Modal Window

Tags: jquery, html, horizontal-scrolling

Anyone know of a good jQuery based horizontal slider that has a modal window that pops up when you click on the image?

I tried many google searches and didn't come up with much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a modal window, that appears after clicking on an image.  And within the modal window, allows you to slide through images?

try [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)